# How to get data from a JSON api and put it in a variable node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get data from an api in Nodejs and put it in a variable, once I get that data I would use different bits of it such as the people who are in space.

I am struggling to find out how here is my code:

```
const request = require("request")

let url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json';

let data = request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    let data;
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = body
    }
    return data
})


console.log(data)
```

My output

[image: My output]

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include text formatted instead of images. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like you've done the hard bit - your output looks like it is probably complete, but you don't give us much info on what you want to extract

Comment: @MikeBrockington I want to extract the json data fron here: http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json

Comment: That is what you have in the image, isn't it?  Is that not actually your output?

Comment: @MikeBrockington — That's the request object, not the body of the response. (The question isn't made clearer by having two different variables named `data` in different scopes).

Comment: @Quentin How do I extract the body of the response?

Comment: @jrmci — You already are, but you're not looking at that value. See the duplicate question.

Comment: @Quentin I should be looking at callbacks, right?

Comment: `(error, response, body) => { ... }` **is** a callback

Comment: @Quentin so what part should I be looking at?

Comment: @jrmci first add few logs for the response and body, you should have a property in response or in body that you can read the json data.